# Angular progress bar with percentage

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular

I have done angular progress circular in my code by refering angular material code.

I want to add percentage while it is loading  Thanks

Comment: Wheeeere? Show us what you've done.

Comment: <md-progress-circular md-mode="determinate" value="..."></md-progress-circular>

<md-progress-circular md-mode="determinate" ng-value="..."></md-progress-circular>

<md-progress-circular md-mode="determinate" value="..." md-diameter="100"></md-progress-circular>

<md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate"></md-progress-circular>

Comment: This is the code. Now i need to add percentage of progress to it

Answer (score 4):

For Angular2+ something along those lines would work:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2ltyru

The idea is pretty simple:

- absolute position the percentage over the progress bar.
- adjust the left property along the way.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, showing percentage or label in circle is not supported if you are using **`md-spinner`** and/or **`md-progress-circle`**.

check here :

1) https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3307

2) https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/1994#issuecomment-285943520

As of now you have to display it outside of the widget as shown here,

https://plnkr.co/edit/lrbuECgLSZjLOMFPvm0s?p=preview

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
      <h1>{{seconds}} seconds</h1>

      <md-progress-circle class="col-xs-4" mode="determinate" value="+{{(seconds*100)/60}}" [attr.aria-valuemax]="max">
          {{seconds}} seconds
      </md-progress-circle>
</div>
```

Concentrate on **`value`** attribute, you need to manipulate it according to your need. by default **`valuemax`** is **`100`**. Here, in my example I'm displaying **`seconds`** which can go max up to **`60 value`**. So I manually play with `value` attribute and converting it to be compatible with **`100 maxvalue`**;