# Angular progressbar with steps

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to make a progress bar with steps in Angular 12, and that the bar advances in a certain way, indicating the percentage of progress. I have seen that the vast majority of examples advance directly from one step to another and not by percentage.It is to show the level of membership and that you know how much is missing to reach the next level.
I have found this example in react [CustomStepper](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-beaver-45ky0?file=/src/CustomStepper.js), does anyone have any similar example for angular 12? Thanks a lot!!

[image]

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42756718/angular-progress-bar-with-percentage. Have a look.

Comment: I've seen it, but it's not what I'm looking for. I need the same as in the codepen example that I have attached, but in angular 12, a progress bar with X steps that are completed according to the percentage of the bar. Thank you very much for the reply!

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is [Angular Stepper](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview) but with a little modification.

[This working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stepper-progress-xszspd?file=src/app/app.component.html) shows how to advance a stepper based on percentage without directly going on to the next step as well as moving to the next level on button click. Try modifying it to cater to your need!

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! It looks very good, I'll try with your example and I'll tell you later

Comment: Welcome. Sure, I hope the answer is acceptable. Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the one provided by Angular Material. Check the [link](https://material.angular.io/components/progress-bar/overview).

In Angular, the way to go when you want to modify the HTML dynamically is to use [property binding](https://angular.io/guide/property-binding). In this case, you bind the `value` property in order to receive dynamic updates from typescript.

Comment: I know the material progress bar, but what I need is a progress bar with steps that completes in a certain way, by percentage or similar [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-beaver-45ky0?file=/src/CustomStepper.js) In the example in react, the progress advances by clicking on the button, but the progress could be indicated by code without problem. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You should bind the `value` property of the angular material progress bar to your typescript. I think the exact functionality you want is not available directly from angular material. So, you would have to play a bit to create the checks you show in your example. But the core idea is to use property binding.

Answer (score 0):

Progress bar takes in basic percent value form `0...100` to determine how much to fill the bar. https://material.angular.io/components/progress-bar/overview

Create a method how you calculate this percentage and pass it to `<mat-progress-bar>`.

```html
<mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" [value]="percent"></mat-progress-bar>
<br />
<br />
<button (click)="onStep(1)">next setp</button
><button (click)="onStep(-1)">previous step</button>
```

```js
/**
 * @title Determinate progress-bar
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'progress-bar-determinate-example',
  templateUrl: 'progress-bar-determinate-example.html',
})
export class ProgressBarDeterminateExample {
  percent: number = 50;
  maxSteps: number = 20;
  currentStep: number = 10;

  onStep(step: number) {
    this.currentStep += step;
    if (this.currentStep > this.maxSteps) {
      this.currentStep = this.maxSteps;
    } else if (this.currentStep < 0) {
      this.currentStep = 0;
    }

    this.percent = (this.currentStep * 100) / this.maxSteps;
    console.log(step);
    console.log(this.percent);
  }
}
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yfwjii?file=src%2Fapp%2Fprogress-bar-determinate-example.ts

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but a simple progress bar is not what I'm looking for, it's a progress bar with several steps, points or trackers like de codepen example